# How to Bind Embedded Image in Code Behind

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to bind the image to the `<Image>` control in Xamarin.

I use followed the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931868/xamarin-form-using-embedded-images)  and I could do this by hard coding the image name in the XAML tag.

But how can I do this in code behind as the image name is from SQLite database and the images are in `Images.MyPages` folder.

XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SApp.Views.SPages"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SApp.MarkupExtensions">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="{local:QEmbeddedImage ResourceId=SApp.Images.SPages.page0.jpg}" x:Name="pageImage" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

using SApp.MarkupExtensions;

namespace SApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SPages : ContentPage
    {
        public SPages()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

`EmbeddedImage` implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace SApp.MarkupExtensions
{
    [ContentProperty("ResourceId")]
    public class QEmbeddedImage : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string ResourceId { get; set; }
        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResourceId))
                return null;
            return ImageSource.FromResource(ResourceId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the images are stored in a folder they should be accessed by file path, not as a resource

Comment: @Jason It is added as EmbeddedResource ( selected in BuildAction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I do this in code behind as the image name is from SQLite database and the images are in Images.MyPages folder.

From your description, you want to display image by code behind, the image is stored in folder, build action as Embedded resource, am I right?

If yes, you can take a look the following code:

```
  <Image
            x:Name="image1"
            HeightRequest="200"
            WidthRequest="200" />
```

Display image by code behind:

```
   public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        image1.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("FormsSample.images.image2.png", typeof(Page1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    }
```

This is my project screenshot:

[image]